# Abstract enum a annotation attribute type

Tags: java, enums, annotations, interface

I have an interface which multiple enums are implementing, i.e

```
public interface MinorCodes {
    public abstract int code();
    public abstract String description();
}

public enum IdentityMinorCodes implements MinorCodes {
    IDENTITY_UPLOAD_PICTURE_CODE(1, "Error while trying to upload a picture."),
}
```

Now I want to have a custom annotation which has a value type of one of these concrete enum values, i.e

```
public @interface PokenService {
    MinorCodes[] exceptions();
}
```

But of course I cannot return an interface here.

Does anyone know any solution or workaround to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an additional enum that wraps all your MinorCodes enum values:

```
public enum MinorCodesWrapper {
    IDENTITY_UPLOAD_PICTURE_CODE(IdentityMinorCodes.IDENTITY_UPLOAD_PICTURE_CODE),
    SOME_CODE(AnotherMinorCodes.SOME_CODE);

    private final MinorCodes _wrapped;

    MinorCodesWrapper(MinorCodes wrapped) {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public MinorCodes getWrapped() {
        return _wrapped;
    }
}

public @interface PokenService {
    MinorCodesWrapper[] exceptions();
}
```

Not pretty, but works ;)